# Solution verification: $\sup S\;\&\;\inf S,\;S:=\left\{\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{c+a}:\;a,b,c\in\langle 0,+\infty\rangle\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum, solution-verification

Find $\sup S\;\&\;\inf S$ if exist.
$$S:=\left\{\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{c+a}:\;a,b,c\in\langle0,+\infty\rangle\right\}$$
My work:

Although it is obvious due to its simmetry, I reformulated the given expression:
$$\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{c+a}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{b}{a}}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{c}{b}}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{a}{c}}<3\implies\sup S=3$$

$A-G\;\text{mean}$ for possible $\min S$ if $\;\inf S\in S:$
$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{b}{a}}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{c}{b}}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{a}{c}}\geq\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{\left(1+\frac{b}{a}\right)\left(1+\frac{c}{b}\right)\left(1+\frac{a}{c}\right)}}$$
The equality holds $\iff\;\;a=b=c$
$$\implies \inf S=\frac{3}{2}\in S\implies\min S=\frac{3}{2}$$

Is this correct?

Note: The set was originally named $A$, but I renamed it not to mix it with $A$ for the $\text{arithmetic mean}$.

Comment: You have shown that $\sup S\leq 3$ but you haven't shown that $\sup S=3.$

Comment: The fact that equality occurs when $a=b=c$ doesn't mean that is the infimum, since the right side might be sometimes less than $\frac{3}{2}.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I see the omission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your solution is not correct.

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b}>\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b+c}=1.$$
Now, for $c\rightarrow0^+$ we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b}\rightarrow\frac{a}{a+b}+1,$$ which for $b\rightarrow+\infty$ is closed to $1$.

Thus, $$\inf\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b}=1.$$

Also $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b}<\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+c}{a+b+c}=2.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I added something. See now.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg , Thank you! I' ll end it.

Comment: You are welcome, Praskovya.

Comment: Specifically, if $(a,b,c)=(1,b,b^{-1})$ then the sum is $\frac{2}{1+b}+\frac{b^2}{b^2+1}.$ Letting $b\to\infty$ you get as close as you want to $1$ and letting $b\to 0^+$ you get as close as you want to $2.$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Yes, of course.